# How can I see what Gmail accounts are using my email as the secondary/backup email?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

I have an older Gmail account that I set up that I need access to. I know that I used my primary Gmail address as the backup account, but I can't remember the username that I used.

I'd swear that I found somewhere in settings or somewhere that I saw this before; but I think there's a place that lets you see what other accounts are using your Gmail account as the secondary account.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AccountA = Older account
AccountB = Primary account

So, what you're saying is that for AccountA, you listed AccountB as the alternate email?  When you did that, Google (at least now they do) sent an email to your AccountB email from account-verification-noreply@google.com and had you verify the association.  If you can find the email and click on the link within it, it should ask you to login to AccountA.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Gmail and choose ‘add new account’ then press the ‘I forgot my email’ button.

You’ll then be prompt to fill in your backup email or phone number. Then you’ll get a message with a list of all your email accounts associated with your backup info.

Comment: Please add the complete path into answer to _'add new account'_ option available in Gmail.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. You will have to enter a first and last name. If you used multiple throwaways it'll be hard to find them all.

Answer (score 1):

If account A is pulling emails from account B using POP3 you can check on https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/accounts.

If account B is forwarding emails to account A then you will have to find an email that was forwarded and check the to address. Perhaps searching for a type of email that would have been delivered to account b.

Account A = primary account being backed up to.

Account B = lost secondary account being backed up from.

Answer (score -1):

go to your mail inbox and type "someone added you as their recovery email" in search bar,
you will find some thing like this [image: wanting to add as a recovery mail address]

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. This is an answer to an ancient question. The old answer has already said some very similar. Considering this, you should try to make your answer better than the previous answers, i.e., you might explain why the search you suggest is a better option than the previous answers or what you know about when Google started to use this wording on the notification messages.

Answer (score -2):

https://families.google.com/families

That did it for me. I got to see all the "child" accounts and could change the password from there. :)